# Can't increase voltage output of class-AB amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, class-ab

I am working on a design project to produce a 2Vpk output across a 10 ohm load from a 10mV, 50kHz input signal. The components shown are the only active components allowed, although in unrestricted quantities. I have come up with the design pictured below but I can't get the voltage across Rload to go above ~1.4Vpk. I have tried increasing the value of R3 and increasing a gain of U1 by adjusting the R8,R9 values but the output voltage stays around 1.4Vpk.

How can I increase the output voltage across Rload?[image]

Comment: Why do you have a 10 nF cap hanging directly on the output of U2? It's only stable into 200 pF unless you use external compensation, and even then it won't drive 10 nF.  So I suspect your circuit may be oscillating.

Comment: Before everything else, test the sub-circuits one by one. Test the preamps individually to see if they do the expected amplification (especially U2 with 10n load), test the push-pull driver stage i.e. disconnect it from the rest of the circuit by removing feedback path (R3) and the op amp output connection but keep C4 in place. Apply 1.4V to the base of Q3 (driver input) and see if you get any output.

Comment: Joe, You need to write something about how you designed that beast. You simply want to increase the output -- simple question -- but it entails me spending way too much time looking it over. I could say simple things as suggestions. But I'd rather see your work product in designing this. That would make it a lot easier to make suggestions. [Here's a design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkIid.png) that may do what you want. It's just cobbled up but in the right ballpark. The bootstrapped 10 Ohm load is at the very top, in case that isn't obvious.

Comment: Your transistor connections don't look right. Q2 collector is trying to pull current from base of Q1, which is odd and not likely to do what you want. Same with Q3 and Q4.

Comment: Increase the voltage gain of the preliminary stage, for example by slightly decreasing R8.

Answer (score 0):

You're running up against the GBW limitations of the op amps. With those values of R2/R3 you only have a bandwidth of 1.1 MHz/51 = 21.5 kHz and you have a 50 kHz input signal. Use an op amp with a higher GBW or add a second pre-amp stage and reduce the gain of U2.